# Запуск jar файла из консоли от maven проекта ОШИБКа

Tags: java, maven, консоль, jar

Есть maven проект, создал его jar  файл, когда запускаю через консоль то получаю ошибку no mainfest attribute in Greeting.jar
В консоле пишу java -jar Greeting.jar
В файле MAINFEST написано

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   Class-Path: D:\Programming\Projects\Java\Greeting\src\main\java
>   Main-Class: Main

в параметрах среды, PATH указал.

В файле maven написано

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>       4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.time</groupId>
<artifactId>mainTime</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.time</groupId>
            <artifactId>mainTime</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Какие плагины для сборки проекта? Покажите из `pom.xml` часть `<build>....</build>`

Comment: <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>

Только что нашел в интернете, но такой вариант не помог(

Comment: Это в `build` добавили? Приведите пож. в пример всю секцию `build`

Comment: Вот весь код из файла maven.

Comment: Добавил ответ, пробуйте

Comment: Все равно ошибка, и у меня в коде <version>2.5</version> подчеркивает. (

Comment: Видимо надо другая версия. Что подсказывает IDE? Cntrl+ Пробел, к примеру, в теге `<version>` нажмите

Comment: 2.3.2 когда вставил то покраснела эта область
 <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>

Comment: Удалите этот блок

Comment: Удалил, не помогло(

Comment: Что теперь пишет? Я обновил ответ, попробуйте как в ответе(привел в пример полностью весь `pom.xml`

Comment: К сожалению и этот вариант не дал результата(

Comment: Что-то пишет? Не компилится?

Comment: В консоле выдает туже ошибку, попробовал этот вариант 
[https://jamandbees.net/2012/04/16/no-main-manifest-attribute-in-maven-jar/]
но он тоже не дал результата и снова подчеркнуло 
 <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
может мне чего нибудь не хватает в проекте? я про библиотеки

Comment: а внутри джарника классы есть?

Answer (score 1):

Пробуйте так. POM.xml должен выгляденть примерно так

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.time</groupId>
    <artifactId>mainTime</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <finalName>mainTime</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```